# How could I get this lemma about stoquastic hamiltonian in the paper "Complexity of stoquastic frustration-free Hamiltonians"

Tags: hamiltonian, stoquatic-matrices

In the paper [Complexity of stoquastic frustration-free Hamiltonians](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1746.pdf), I was confused about the derivation of Lemma 4.5: How could we get $\delta Tr(O(I-\Pi_a)) \leq Tr(OH_a)$ given that $\delta (I-\Pi_a) \leq H_a$? (I think the $\leq$ sign here should be the partial order for positive semidefinite matrix)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is obviously incorrect for general O: Just change O to -O.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now I am curious about how could we get Lemma 4.5 here. Would you mind giving some explanations on the way for proving this lemma?